# Notifications not being sent on status change in order manager

Tags: cartthrob

I am trying to trigger an email notification  when changing the status of an order from within Order Manager. The trigger works when editing the order from Cartthrob but not Order Manager. I tried both "Oder status has been changed" and "Cartthrob_order_manager: Order_updated" as triggers. Anyone know if this is a bug in Order Manager or am I forgetting something?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If I find a resolution I will let you know.

Comment: The original issue was posted a year and three months ago and the problem is still persists. I'm running EE 2.8.1 and CT 2.6. Status update emails are not being sent when updated through the Order Manager. The only way to send a status update is by updating it through the EE publish entry screen. I would ask my client to handle updating the shipping status this way, however I'm getting a Grid parser error when updating the entry to "Shipped" Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: 87 Filename: libraries/Grid_parser.php I've sent a phone call request to CartThrob with a reference to this thr

Comment: They'll probably tell you to update CT and EE. I had some unrelated-but-weird-issues and updating both seemed to do the trick. You might want to go that route. I'd clone everything over to a DEV site, change the DB settings and upgrade everything there to see if the upgrade fixes your issues too.